# How to develop a code for grouping the Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

How to group Combobox in c#.A picture format is shown here.

!http://www.brad-smith.info/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/GroupedComboBox.jpg

Comment: What have you actually tried? We're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: sorry for making trouble sir.actually i need help for the above question.please help me

Comment: It's not a question.. please read the rules, have a go at this yourself and then post a question when you run into a specific problem.

Answer (score -1):

create a string array of what you want,

```
string items = {"A","B","C"};
```

add this item source to your comboBox

```
comboBox1.ItemSource = items;
```

Most of these things are available on stackoverflow already. Try not to post questions like this without searching and getting info about it.

Comment: ItemSource? Even if you meant DataSource, I'm not sure how this addresses the "grouping" part of the question.